# Evaluate condition of if in python

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the AST of a python program and want to manually evaluate the condition of an if statement.

```
cond = node.test
b = eval(compile(cond,"<string>","eval"))
print b
```

Where node is the If-Node, gives me *TypeError: expected Expression node, got Compare*, even if Compare is an expression according to the grammar in the python doc of ast.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `ast.expr` subclass, **not** a `ast.Expression` top-level node.

`compile()` can only take a `mod` object, so one of `Module`, `Interactive` or `Expression`, depending on the third argument to `compile()`. For `'eval'`, use `ast.Expression()`.

You can create one *containing* the `ast.Compare` node:

```
expr = ast.Expression(cond)
```

because the [abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) defines it as:

```
Expression(expr body)
```

and this you can compile:

```
compile(expr, '<file>', 'eval')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> code = "if foo == 'bar': pass"
>>> tree = ast.parse(code, '<file>', 'exec')
>>> cond = tree.body[0].test
>>> expr = ast.Expression(cond)
>>> compile(expr, '<file>', 'eval')
<code object <module> at 0x1067f6230, file "<file>", line 1>
>>> foo = 'baz'
>>> eval(compile(expr, '<file>', 'eval'))
False
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> eval(compile(expr, '<file>', 'eval'))
True
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see there is a difference. Could I just pass *cond* to the constructor of ast.Expression, and use this object?

Comment: @user1839433: ah, my mistake; `Expression()` takes **one** `expr` field, not a list of them.